# A jquery .toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject) [,...) function is executed by its own

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I've used the jquery .toggle(between two functions) in my webpage :

```
  $( ".cpUpbtnsclass" ).toggle(function() {
    console.log( "cpUpbtnsclass's clicked !" );
    }, function() {
        console.log( "cpUpbtnsclass's RE-clicked !" );
    });
```

When the page is loaded for the first time, i see the message written on those functions on the console log. I also noticed that elements precisely with the class="cpUpbtnsclass" (and not class="xxx cpUpbtnsclass" have their CSS property display:none; not working. As soon as i just commented the above jquery code, everything returns normal (i get rid of these sympthoms)

the following is the html elements for which the toggle events are related :

```
<div id="cropUploadbtns" >

<div id="upldimgbtn" class="displ1 cpUpbtnsclass" style="position:absolute; z-index:120; top:450px; left:70px; height:20px; width:165px; background-image: url('ressources/tunmecgenress/images/chngimgbtn.png'); display:none;">
<div id="uploadWholeimgDiv" style="position:absolute; top:-119px; left:14px;z-index:100; display:none;">
<img src="ressources/tunmecgenress/images/uploadWholeimg.png" />
</div>
<span style="margin-left:15px;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:7px; color:yellow;" >Uploader l'image enti&#232;re</span>
</div>

<div id="cropimgbtn" class="displ1 cpUpbtnsclass" style="position:absolute; z-index:120; top:480px;  left:70px; height:20px; width:215px; background-image: url('ressources/tunmecgenress/images/selectzonebtn.png'); display:none; ">
<span style="margin-left:15px;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:7px; color:yellow;" >S&#233;lectionner une zone de l'image</span>
</div>

<div id="upldselctedzon" class="cpUpbtnsclass"  style="position:absolute;z-index:110; top:495px; left:-50px; height:30px; width:300px; display:none;">
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;">
<img src="ressources/tunmecgenress/images/upldselctedzon.png" />
</div>
<span style="position:absolute; top:12px; left:30px; margin-left:15px;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:7px; color:yellow;" >Uploader la zone selectionn&#233;e</span>
</div>

<div id="chngimgbtn" class="displ1 cpUpbtnsclass" style="position:absolute;z-index:120; top:510px; left:70px; height:20px; width:165px; background-image: url('ressources/tunmecgenress/images/chngimgbtn.png'); display:none;">
<span style="margin-left:15px;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:7px; color:yellow;" >Choisir une autre image </span>
</div>


<div id="deselectimgbtn" class="cpUpbtnsclass" style="position:absolute;z-index:110; top:430px; left:199px; height:40px; width:116px;z-index:4;display:none;">
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;">
<img src="ressources/tunmecgenress/images/deselectimgbtn.png" />
</div>
<span style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:0px; margin-left:15px;font-size:12px;font-weight: bold; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:7px; color:yellow;" >D&#233;selectionner </span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: as u are not specifying the event on which it has to be happened .on document load that function ius running

Comment: check console! Which jq version are you using? Toggle event method has been removed: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: i ve doubts about it's deprected.. i'm using the jq v2.0.3. OK! but is there an alternative to it now?

Comment: Sure, just use click event with some little logic using a element state as flag

Comment: a logic like a boolean :) thanks

Comment: @Bardelman or use `.data()` to store the current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that for example:

```
$(".cpUpbtnsclass").click(function () {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    if (this.toggle) {
        console.log("cpUpbtnsclass's clicked !");
    } else {
        console.log("cpUpbtnsclass's RE-clicked !");
    }
});
```